# Print out certain elements in a list

Tags: java, list, collections

I have list of strings (list collection)
my question is how do you print out the very first string,

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("octopus");
        list.add("fish");
        list.add("shark");
```

Comment: `System.out.println(list.get(0));` ???

Comment: `System.out.println(list.get(0));`

Comment: Have you looked at the docs?

Comment: Next time do your homework!....System.out.println(list.getFirst());

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow...I guess you need to go thru the rules to be followed before posting a question. I'm sure this question will be flagged and removed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print out the first item in the list do:

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

The `.get(0);` gets the string at index 0. Lists start at 0, so the first value in the list is at index 0.

[Java docs about `.get(index)` for a LinkedList.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int))

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

Comment: @danwright Do you mind accepting the answer as correct then? Thanks :-)

Comment: Could add that `LinkedList` also has a `getFirst()` method.